# Waiting between button events on a website

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I want to wait between 2 click events because the second event depends on the result of the first event.

My code to make it clear:

```
    '**************************************************************************
    'Adding piece number to the webbrowser control
    '26/12/2019 Kris Bauwens
    '**************************************************************************
    Web.Document.GetElementById("hwbOrPiece").InnerText = txtSID.Text
    Web.Document.GetElementById("hwbOrPiece").RemoveFocus()
    SearchHWB()

Private Sub SearchHWB()
    '**************************************************************************
    'Search if the piece number exist, if so look for the history
    '27/12/2019 Kris Bauwens
    '**************************************************************************
    Dim HtmlElementcol As HtmlElementCollection = Web.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
    For Each elem As HtmlElement In HtmlElementcol
        If elem.InnerText = "search " Then
            elem.Focus()
            'Invoke event
            elem.InvokeMember("click")
            Thread.Sleep(3000) ''''''''''''''''''''''''-> not really working
            Do While blnFind = False
                SearchHistory()
            Loop
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    blnFind = False
End Sub

Private Function SearchHistory() As Boolean
    '**************************************************************************
    'Look for the history
    '27/12/2019 Kris Bauwens
    '**************************************************************************
    Dim HtmlElementcol As HtmlElementCollection = Web.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
    For Each elem As HtmlElement In HtmlElementcol
        Debug.Print(elem.InnerText)
        If elem.InnerText = "SD History " Then
            elem.Focus()
            'Invoke event
            elem.InvokeMember("click")
            blnFind = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Return blnFind
End Function
```

I tried it with 'Thread' but it goes to fast.  The system starts already with the second event and is not waiting for the first.  It's even not waiting for the innertext to execute.

How can I solve this?

Comment: That's not how it works. On the first event you set a `Boolean` flag to indicate that that event has occurred. On the second event, you check for that flag.  You know, just like in real life.

Comment: I tried several things...

Comment: Does the page do a full refresh when you click the button element?  If so you could throw the logic in the documentcomplete event for SearchHistory.  Though, it looks like you're trying to manipulate someone else's page I assume?  It might be easier to use something like Fiddler and send/receive the raw data vs manipulate the DOM via web control.  You'll get much more consistent results that way.

Comment: It's not a full refresh.  I programmed it also in VBA and I get there Javascript / Angular errormessages.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced Thread.Sleep by the old Application.DoEvents() (Visual Basic until 1998)
I don't like it, other suggestions?